# IDEA и static перемененные

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при использовании оператора " . " не показывается статическая переменная t ? 
При том что если ее все же написать то ошибки не будет. 
Почему при этом IDEA советует воспользоваться Имякласса.t ?

Comment: Потому что вы обращаетесь к *экземпляру*, а t относится к *классу*. Несмотря на то, что экземпляр предоставляет доступ к этой переменной, эта переменная - не его.

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к статическому члену через экземпляр объекта считается моветоном. При написании такого кода компиляторы и IDE обычно выдают предупреждения. 
Правильным считается обращение через имя класса.